# How to create an invoice for a sales order Quickbooks Desktop

Tags: quickbooks

I have a customer in Quickbook Desktop, so that I have generated a slaes order for the particular customer, now for the customer sales order I have to generate a invoice. . When I tried it I got the following error. How to link a quickbook desktop customer sales order to a invoice?
I tried using  IDTYPE attribute. What is wrong here? Kindly help

```
0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
Parsing response.
Processing response.
Job 'create_invoice' received response: ''.
```

This is my sales order xml response.

```
{"xml_attributes"=>{},
  "txn_id"=>"75-1640702627",
  "time_created"=>"2021-12-28T14:43:47+00:00",
  "time_modified"=>"2021-12-28T14:43:47+00:00",
  "edit_sequence"=>"1640702627",
  "txn_number"=>37,
  "customer_ref"=>{"xml_attributes"=>{}, "list_id"=>"80000001-1640593593", "full_name"=>"Test Customer"},
  "template_ref"=>{"xml_attributes"=>{}, "list_id"=>"80000008-1640593060", "full_name"=>"Custom Sales Order"},
  "txn_date"=>"2021-12-28",
  "ref_number"=>"18",
  "bill_address"=>{"xml_attributes"=>{}, "addr1"=>"212 W. Chskskss St.", "addr2"=>"Ste.100", "addr3"=>"wqw, Parròquia d'Encamp www", "addr4"=>"Andorra"},
  "bill_address_block"=>{"xml_attributes"=>{}, "addr1"=>"212 W. Chskskss St.", "addr2"=>"Ste.100", "addr3"=>"wqw, Parròquia d'Encamp www", "addr4"=>"Andorra"},
  "due_date"=>"2021-12-28",
  "ship_date"=>"2021-12-28",
  "subtotal"=>1.0,
  "sales_tax_percentage"=>0.0,
  "sales_tax_total"=>0.0,
  "total_amount"=>1.0,
  "is_manually_closed"=>false,
  "is_fully_invoiced"=>false,
  "is_to_be_printed"=>true,
  "is_to_be_emailed"=>false}
```

Trying to generate invoice for this particular sales order
Here is my invoice XML attributes that I am sending to Quickbook Desktop

```
    xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="7.0"?>
    <QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <InvoiceAddRq >  
         <InvoiceAdd>
            <CustomerRef>
               <FullName>Test Customer</FullName >
              </CustomerRef>
               <BillAddress>
                  <Addr1>212 W. Chskskss St.</Addr1>
                  <Addr2>Ste.100</Addr2>
                  <City>wqw</City>
                  <State>Parròquia d'Encamp www</State>
                  <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                  <Country>Andorra</Country>
                </BillAddress>
            <InvoiceLineAdd>
                <ItemRef>
                    <FullName >Inspection Request</FullName> 
                </ItemRef>
                <Desc >plants</Desc>
                <Quantity >1</Quantity> 
                <Amount >50.00</Amount>
            </InvoiceLineAdd>
          <LinkToTxnID>75-1640702627<LinkToTxnID>
          </InvoiceAdd>
        </InvoiceAddRq>
      </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>'
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing coming to my mind is: "Where is your closing QBXML tag?"

```
</QBXML>
```

Beside that. The SDK includes an XML Validator tool which you can use to validate the XML structure. Try to use this to see where your structure probably does not meet the requirements.

Comment: I missed to add it here. Added now